# returning NIL from empy pathway from Ruby parser

Tags: ruby, parsing

I'm trying to return NIL from any empty pathway in my code. I'm using spec test to run this. If the URL is `https://www.google.com/?q=cat#img=FunnyCat` and I'm trying to grab everything between **`'/'`** (slash) and **`'?'`** (question mark). How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry if I ask, in what code?

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you can utilize the URI module.

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI("https://www.google.com/?q=cat#img=FunnyCat")
uri.path.sub("/", "").blank? ? nil : uri.path # => nil
```

The above will return `nil` for empty paths.

URI Module docs [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).